# Async Mocha done() isn't called in my function

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, webstorm, chai

I call this function, console log is called but done() is not called:

```
import {Database} from "../../code/server/Database";
import 'mocha'
const expect = require('chai').expect

describe('Database save', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
        Database.saveSessionData(1, 2, 3, function(err, docs) {
            expect(err).to.equal(null)
            expect(docs.sessionOpenTime).to.equal(1)
            expect(docs.sessionCloseTime).to.equal(2)
            expect(docs.sessionLength).to.equal(3)
            console.log(2222)
            done()
        })
    })
})
```

Here is the result, 'Running tests' continues spinning on forever:

[image: result]

But if I change the 'Database' code into this, it works as expected:

```
setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('lol')
            done()
        }, 1000)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the callback function in `Database.saveSessionData` called?

Comment: Usually there is an error before the `done()`. Try wrap your expectation in try catch, and console.log/error the exception.

Comment: @marcel it is called, so 2222 is printed.

Comment: @TomMarulak I just tried putting the whole callback result in try catch, and tried doing the whole Database.saveblabla in try catch. No error showed up. Also the database is working fine and the results of the callback is as expected.

Comment: Try comment out your expectations and add simple test like `expect(true).to.equal(true); done();`. see if this is working fine, if yes try to uncomment the assertion one by one. Sometimes I had to wrap the assertion in the try catch as mocha will swallow the error.

Comment: Ok, it seems the expectation are working fine, but done isn't working. https://image.prntscr.com/image/Zxxi5jObTAisyQ3rI2UAsw.png

Comment: According to the picture you have provided, your test sucessfully passed, It seems to me like your mocha test just hangs since you have opened database connection. Usually you don't want to test on real database connection and use mocks/stubs/dependency injection to inject test behaviour for async utility libraries.

Comment: by the way, if you still want to create real db connection you can use the `after` hook of mocha library - it would launch your provided callback after all tests where you would call something like `Database.closeConnection()`.

Comment: @NikMarkin I do want to test on a real db connection. Thats kind of the point. But, thanks for the answer, its weird but it that worked. I expected done() to kill remaining processes, it seems thats not how it works. Answer it officially?

Comment: @Esqarrouth added my answer, if you have some additional questions to make the answer more complete, feel free to ask in the comments to the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mocha test hangs since you have an opened database connection.

There are two options to solve this problem:

### If you do not need a real database connection in your tests:

- you can use `sinon.stub()` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) to return a predetermined response for async methods you use in your tests or `sinon.spy()` to make sure a stubbed method called exact number of times.

  Here's a good article I just found to illustrate how to use sinon.js: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js.
- you can implement a dependency injection container to be able to replace your implementation of `Database` class to a `Database` class that does not perform I/O operations.

  Although dependency injection implementations may vary depending on requirements some simple implementations are also available:

  https://blog.risingstack.com/dependency-injection-in-node-js/

### If you need to perform a real connection in your tests:

- Consider adding an `after` hook to your mocha tests:

let's say mongodb is used as a database (it does not matter, but it would
be an actual working example)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

after(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close();
});

describe('db connection', () => {
  it('should make a test', () => {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```